# Android EditText Money Input Style Without Dollar Symbol

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, charsequence

I want to money input box without dollar symbol. There is a code which works fine with dollars

```
            private int price = 0;
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!s.toString().matches("^\\$(\\d{1,3}(\\,\\d{3})*|(\\d+))(\\.\\d{2})?")) {
                    String userInput = "" + s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                    if (userInput.length() > 2) {
                        Float in = Float.parseFloat(userInput);
                        price = Math.round(in); // just to get an Integer
                        //float percen = in/100;
                        String first, last;
                        first = userInput.substring(0, userInput.length() - 2);
                        last = userInput.substring(userInput.length() - 2);
                        inputAmount.setText("$" + first + "." + last);
                        Log.e(FragTutar.class.toString(), "first: " + first + " last:" + last);
                        inputAmount.setSelection(inputAmount.getText().length());
                    }
                }}
        });
```

i tried all ways and i couldn't remove $ sysmbol. How can i remove on this code?

Comment: will you able to post your full code

Comment: this part is enough for fixing bro

Comment: Am trying i will post soon

Comment: thanks bro im waiting for it

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line

```
inputAmount.setText("$" + first + "." + last);
```

to this

```
inputAmount.setText(first + "." + last);
```

Comment: i changed but program will forced close